# How to resolve pop index out of range error in python?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

This is my code:

```
while k != 24:
   p1 = random.choice(list1)
   p2 = random.choice(list1)
   r = (p1, p2)
   list2.append(r)
   l = list1.index(p1)
   p = list1.index(p2)
   list1.pop(l)
   list1.pop(p)
   k += 1
```

if I run this code the following error is prompted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/PyCharm/pythonProject1/main.py", line 24, in <module>
list1.pop(p)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

it works fine when there is only one pop command:

```
while k != 24:
   p1 = random.choice(list1)
   p2 = random.choice(list1)
   r = (p1, p2)
   list2.append(r)
   #l = list1.index(p1)
   p = list1.index(p2)
   #list1.pop(l)
   list1.pop(p)
   k += 1
```

Why the the above mentioned error is prompted when I use two pop commands in one loop and works fine with one pop command?

Comment: Just move the line `p = list1.index(p2)` right after the first `pop` call, because the first `pop` call changes the list and the index of `p2` become wrong in the case when `l <= p`.

Comment: The first time you use `pop` all the indices to the right shift.

Comment: @sergey thank you and @juanpa.arrivillaga I know it thats why I am using that or I would have directly used ```list1.pop(p2)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the line `p = list1.index(p2)` right before poping it, because the first `pop` call changes the list and the index of `p2` become wrong in the case when `l <= p`. So the code should look like

```py
while k != 24:
   p1 = random.choice(list1)
   p2 = random.choice(list1)
   r = (p1, p2)
   list2.append(r)
   l = list1.index(p1)
   list1.pop(l)
   p = list1.index(p2)
   list1.pop(p)
   k += 1
```